# Creating MongoDB image error from Docker official tutorial

Tags: docker

Here is [the official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/mongodb/#creating-a-dockerfile-for-mongodb) to create mongoDB img.

I followed exactly the tutorial and generated the following Dockerfile

```
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/mongodb/#creating-a-dockerfile-for-mongodb
# Dockerizing MongoDB: Dockerfile for building MongoDB images
# Based on ubuntu:latest, installs MongoDB following the instructions from:
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

# Format: FROM    repository[:version]
FROM       ubuntu:latest

# Installation:
# Import MongoDB public GPG key AND create a MongoDB list file
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list


# Update apt-get sources AND install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org

# MongoDB requires a data directory. Let’s create it as the final step of our installation instructions.
# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

# Expose port 27017 from the container to the host
EXPOSE 27017

# Set usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

But when I execute

```
$ docker build --tag my/repo .
```

I got the following error:

[image]

What is going on? Why it fails? How to fix it?

EDIT:

After adjust the command order, my final script is this:

```
# Format: FROM    repository[:version]
FROM       ubuntu:latest


# Update apt-get sources AND install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update 

# Installation:
# Import MongoDB public GPG key AND create a MongoDB list file
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
# RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org

# MongoDB requires a data directory. Let’s create it as the final step of our installation instructions.
# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

# Expose port 27017 from the container to the host
EXPOSE 27017

# Set usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

Then I got the following error: [image]

Next, then I added "RUN apt-get install sudo", then I got the following error:

[image]
[image]

3 strikes down, I am not confident this whole thing will work. Here is my final Dockerfile.

```
    # https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/mongodb/#creating-a-dockerfile-for-mongodb
    # Dockerizing MongoDB: Dockerfile for building MongoDB images
    # Based on ubuntu:latest, installs MongoDB following the instructions from:
    # http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

# Format: FROM    repository[:version]
FROM       ubuntu:latest


# Update apt-get sources AND install MongoDB
RUN apt-get update 

# Installation:
# Import MongoDB public GPG key AND create a MongoDB list file
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common

RUN apt-get install sudo

# RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org

# MongoDB requires a data directory. Let’s create it as the final step of our installation instructions.
# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db

# Expose port 27017 from the container to the host
EXPOSE 27017

# Set usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

If you can make it work, please paste your Dockerfile and I'd love to learn what is wrong in my script. I followed the tutorial and it doesn't work.

Comment: What did google say when you searched for that error message?

Comment: @Soviut many results, I am not be able to identify relevancy.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for your exact error message found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706704/unable-to-locate-package-software-properties-common).

This is an error from `apt` saying it can't find the `software-properties-common` package in its repositories. When a package change be found, it usually means apt needs updating.

You are running `apt-get update` but you're running it *after* the update line.

```
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Instead, run it first

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
...
RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

**Update:** Your update says you're now getting an error when installing the mongodb package. This is because you've loaded a `deb` package file and need to update apt yet again so that it knows about it. At this point, the easiest thing to do is just prefix any `apt-get` commands that complain about not finding packages with an `update`.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It passed that step, but got new error "E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org". I am not able to fix it based on google search result.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu I've updated my answer to include a solution to monogo not installing.